# Adding a line of Json to a Json file

Tags: c#, json

I am writing a script to make configuration of a client automated. I want to be able to read a json file, and add a line in the existing json.

I have got as far as to read the json file - however I need some help with the editing of the json file

```
var pathToJson = Path.Combine(@"C:\" + DownloadConfigFilelocation);
var r = new StreamReader(pathToJson);
var myJson = r.ReadToEnd();
```

I need to add the line

```
"pageTitle": "Base Client",
```

to the json file below

[image: Json file]

I need to add this under "name".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest option is to treat it as JSON: add a property, not a line:

```
// Load the content of the file as a string
string json = File.ReadAllText(pathToJson);

// Parse the JSON to a Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

// Add the property
obj["pageTitle"] = "Base Client";

// Convert back to a JSON string
string newJson = obj.ToString();

// Save the string back to the file
File.WriteAllText(pathToJson, newJson);
```

This requires the [`Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) (aka Json.NET).

Comment: Thanks @Daisy - This makes perfect sense.